# data-binding radio field in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am using redux-form v8.1.0.
There is a Boolean field IsCompulsary in the db.
How to make 'Yes' checked if it is true, and 'No' checked if it is false?

```
    <div>
      <label>
        <Field
          name="IsCompulsary"
          component="input"
          type="radio"              
        />{' '}
        Yes
      </label>
      <label>
        <Field
          name="IsCompulsary"
          component="input"
          type="radio"             
        />{' '}
        No
      </label>
    </div>
```

Update:

At the bottom of the component:

```
SchoolSettings = reduxForm({
  form: "schoolSettingsForm", // a unique identifier for this form
  enableReinitialize: true
})(SchoolSettings);
 SchoolSettings = connect(
  state => ({
  initialValues: state.schoolSettings.data // pull initial values from account reducer
})   
)(SchoolSettings);

export default SchoolSettings;
```

Data is :

```
{Id: 1, Name: "Our School", IsCompulsary: true}
```

Comment: How do you initialise your redux-form? How the data looks like?

Comment: @Dario : Have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the value fields to your radio inputs and normalize their values so that they are converted to boolean before they update the store:

```
<div>
  <label>
    <Field
      name="IsCompulsary"
      component="input"
      type="radio"
      value={true} 
      normalize={value => value === 'true'}           
    />{' '}
    Yes
  </label>
  <label>
    <Field
      name="IsCompulsary"
      component="input"
      type="radio"    
      value={false}   
      normalize={value => value === 'true'}                    
    />{' '}
    No
  </label>
</div>
```

Check sandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/serene-banach-nviml

Comment: This code displays radio button checked depending on what is in the db, which is correct. But if "Yes" was checked and I click on "No", both of them turn unchecked. Then neither of them can be checked.

Comment: Hard to say what could be wrong. Can you share some more code, maybe using a sandbox on https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-star-6wvxe
Click on "Load Account" and then try clicking on "Yes".

Comment: Got it, value will be set as a string "true" or "false", you need to convert to Boolean passing a `normalize` function of the field. Updated the answer, check also https://codesandbox.io/embed/serene-banach-nviml